# prove , if $p,q$ be two primes with the property , $q$=$p$+1 then $p$=2 and $q$=3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

prove , if $p,q$ are two primes with the property , $q$=$p$+1 then $p$=2 and $q$=3

how can we prove something like that ?

my information in number theory is not big , and i have no idea about the method which we should follow to prove this statement .

any ideas ?

remark ! : this is Not homework , it's just a question .

Comment: Think about the parity of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Out of two consecutive integers one must be even and one must be odd. Since there is only one even prime, $2$ (since all other even numbers are divisible by it), the above is the only possibility.

Comment: In general, given a sequence of k consecutive integers and some r ($0\leq r<k$), one of the members of the sequence must leave the remainder r when divided by k. In addition to solving the question here, we can, for instance, show that there is no way for four consecutive integers to all be squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is a prime number greater than $2$. Then $p$ is an odd prime number.

Then $q=p+1$ must be an even number, which cannot be a prime number.

So the only pair of prime numbers $(p, q)$ satisfying $q=p+1$ is $(2, 3)$.

Answer (score 2):

First prove that either q or p is even, then prove that there's only one even prime number, finally prove that p=2.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:If you take any two consecutive integers at least one must be even (Prove it) . And there's only one even prime number (Prove it).